# write data into txt file with 2 column of data

Tags: c#

i have program that read from serial port and write them into text but i need time of data that come into my PC i cant adding time in front of the data

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append);
                var data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(temp);
                      //  int time;
                       // time =Convert.ToInt32( DateTime.Today);
                      //  MessageBox.Show(time.ToString());
               fileStream.Write(data+//code?? , 0, data.Length);
           fileStream.Close();

                        }
```

Comment: What problem did you face with commented code? How do you expect the time value look like in the file?

Comment: visual studio did n't accept that code . i want write my data like this:
data    time

Comment: What error visual studio shows?

Comment: What error visual studio shows?

Comment: fileStream.Write(data+" "+ Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now) , 0, data.Length); for this code cannot convert from string to byte[] –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `temp` is of type String.
Add `DateTime.Now` before you convert the temp-Variable to a ByteArray.
Change this line...

```
var data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(temp);
```

to...

```
var data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("{0} {1}",temp, DateTime.Now));
```

or to just get the time of day...

```
var data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("{0} {1}",temp, DateTime.Now.ToString("T")));
```

Comment: thank and i need just time of day .
date is not use full for me what should i do to remove date from it?

Comment: @tr_pouya - Just change `DateTime.Now` to `DateTime.Now.ToString("T")`

Comment: And maybe have a look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ;-)